# What is Zend's console? When do you use this console?

Tags: zend-framework

Does any one know what is the use of Zend's console?

any sample program ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Console = the shell, or command line. If you have Windows go to Run and enter 'cmd', if you have a Mac open Terminal. Console scripts are useful for long processes or things you want to schedule to occur on a regular basis (the 'cron' RaYell refers to).

For example, I wrote a link checker script for checking links for websites we develop. It's used to help QA sites and check for errors. That command looks something like:

php linkchecker.php http://www.domain.com

The third bit is any arguments that are passed to the script. These can easily be accessed via Zend Console Getopt which is the only stable component of Zend_Console I'm aware of.

More info on Zend Console Getopt - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.console.getopt.html

There are details of Zend Console itself which are on the developer wiki, but I don't know if this is currently being developed - http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Console+-+Wil+Sinclair

Answer (score 3):

Zend console allows you to write console apps in PHP. It can be very useful if i.e. you want to run certain actions of your app with CRON.